# How to retrive output depending on last alphabet from entry in table

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I have table User with Id, Name. So depending on last alphabet from column Name, i need to output some text.

If last char is 'o' should return YES, if is 'i' return NO, else null

Ex. 
Monika Levinski ---> last is 'i', output NO

Ronaldo ---> last is 'o', output YES

Messi ---> last is 'i', output No

Costa ---> null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a CASE expression like the example below.  Note that USER is a reserved keyword so I suggest you avoid using that as a table or column name.  If you must use a reserved keyword, it must be enclosed in brackets or double-quotes.

```
SELECT  Id
      , Name
      , CASE RIGHT(Name, 1)
          WHEN 'o' THEN 'YES'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'NO'
        END AS SomeText
FROM    dbo.[User];
```

Below is a cursor example as you requested.

```
DECLARE @id int
  , @Name varchar(30)
  , @SomeText varchar(3);
DECLARE user_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  id
          , Name
          , CASE RIGHT(Name, 1)
              WHEN 'o' THEN 'YES'
              WHEN 'i' THEN 'NO'
            END AS SomeText
    FROM    dbo.[User];
OPEN user_cursor;
WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM user_cursor INTO @id, @Name, @SomeText;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1
            BREAK;
        RAISERROR('Id=%d, Name=%s, SomeText=%s', 0, 0, @id, @Name, @SomeText);
    END;
CLOSE user_cursor;
DEALLOCATE user_cursor;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i needed, can i ask you to give me some hints how to make this statement using Cursor.

Comment: @PetarS, Cursors should generally be avoided in SQL Server in favor of set-based statements.  I'll add a T-SQL cursor example to my answer for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the info, and for the help. Excuse me @Dan Guzman - SQL Server, can i ask you is it possible the output 'SomeText' to be with name. Ex. instead of Name=Ronaldo, SomeText=Yes, to be SomeText = YES.Ronaldo ?

Comment: @PetarS, you can change "END AS SomeText" to "END + '.' + Name" to add a period and the name to the end.